# Minifilter Check new file create on harddisk?

Tags: c++, windows, driver, minifilter

I am developping a minifilter. I check a new file creation (by drag & drop) on a harddisk (i.e D:). I do as below:

```
isNewFile = FALSE;
if (Data
    && Data->Iopb
    && (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE))
{
   // Get create disposition
   createDisposition = (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24) & 0x000000FF;

   // Check if new file is creating or not
   isNewFile = ((FILE_SUPERSEDE == createDisposition)
                || (FILE_CREATE == createDisposition)
                || (FILE_OPEN_IF == createDisposition)
                || (FILE_OVERWRITE == createDisposition)
                || (FILE_OVERWRITE_IF == createDisposition));

   // Write log
   PT_DBG_PRINT( PTDBG_TEST_STATUS,
                    ("isNewFile %d--createDisposition: <%08x>\n",
                                    isNewFile,
                                    createDisposition));
}
```

The value of create options

```
//
// Define the create disposition values at wdm.h
//
#define FILE_SUPERSEDE                  0x00000000
#define FILE_OPEN                       0x00000001
#define FILE_CREATE                     0x00000002
#define FILE_OPEN_IF                    0x00000003
#define FILE_OVERWRITE                  0x00000004
#define FILE_OVERWRITE_IF               0x00000005
#define FILE_MAXIMUM_DISPOSITION        0x00000005
```

1. When I drag & drop file(s) from desktop, isNewFile flag is TRUE

   - isNewFile 1--createDisposition: <0x00000002>
2. When I drag & drop file(s) from Windows Explorer, isNewFile is always FALSE.

   - isNewFile 0--createDisposition: <0x00000001>

**Is there anything wrong?**

Thanks all.

Comment: Is this the only IRP_MJ_CREATE for the file? Or is Windows Explorer doing something like trying to open it to check if it exists, or for some other reason? You probably need to look at something like process explorer to try to understand what Explorer is doing and why it's open/creating the file in different ways.

Comment: I tested many times, but I don't know the reason why isNewFile flag is false when I use  all **List all of the requests to filter**. Now, I use only IRP_MJ_CREATE request, It work well.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Drag and Drop , if this happens within same volume its goes through FltSetInformationFile as rename. but if the volume are different then it would new file created @ destination file contents are copied across. You can check this behavior with tools like [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx).